# Android BLE peripheral with pin pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an Android app which behaves as Bluetooth peripheral role with a service.

When I start advertising, other Android devices searching for devices offering this service, can see my device (and can pair to it without pin) - ok.

But how to enable PIN pairing?

Comment: Just an idea. I guess you will offer a GattServer with some characteristics. Have you tried to configure your characteristics with e.g. BluetoothGattCharacterisitic.PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED_MITM. I haven't tried it, but that might help. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED_MITM

Comment: I tried this, but it did not help...

Comment: Ok, that's sad. I do not have any further ideas.

Comment: You could access the characteristic without having paired with a PIN?

Comment: Why don't you use 'normal' bluetooth if you want to have a PIN protected pairing?

Answer (score 4):

You can force the device has to be paired, when using specific characteristics by protecting them with [PERMISSION_READ_ENCRYPTED_MITM](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattDescriptor.html#PERMISSION_READ_ENCRYPTED_MITM) or PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED_MITM.

The client/central side can force pairing by calling [BluetoothDevice.creteBond()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()).

The pairing method itself is determinated by the bluetooth protocol (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677164/ble-peripheral-pairing-pin-on-android))

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually require pairing to be done to transmit/receive data via ble, take a look into [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) tutorial

Comment: I know, but I WANT to use pairing with pin ;)