# How to authenticate bluetooth communication between Raspberry and Android

Tags: android, authentication, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, pairing

I created an application on the Raspberry (using QT bluetooth module) that publishes a service with a specific UUID and waits on a rfcomm socket. I was able from my Android application to pair with the Raspberry, to find the service and exchange data using sockets. The Android application simply asks to the user if he wants to pair with the Raspberry, without pin confirmation. Now I would like to add an authentication step, a simple pin or passkey, to allow the connection only to those who know it. I can change the Android application to show a dialog allowing the user to insert the pin, in such a way the application on Raspberry can verify the correctness of the pin and eventually close the socket, but this solution is obviously valid only for the devices with my application. Is there a way to implement a similar solution during the pairing process, in order to make it available to every devices? I tried among the QT functions but I didn't find anything that could help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your design which is if you plan on authenticating with a pin the raspberry pi needs some way to tell the user what the pin should be. If you don't have a screen or output of some kind on the raspberry pi then the pin would be useless because you have no way to generate a random pin and then tell the user what it should be.
Depending on the application you are usually fine not having an authentication pin ect. Think about most Bluetooth devices you use, none of them have any authentication you can just click pair.

Here are some other options I can think of:
1) Detect when you have already connected to a device on the raspberry pi and not broadcast the service so once you are connected to a device another device cant also connect and cause issues.
2) Have a button on the raspberry pi and only broadcast the publish service for 1 min after pressing the button
3) get a screen or someway of outputting information to the user from the raspberry pi to show them the pin to enter on their phone

Comment: you're right, I forgot to say something. I thought to hardcode the pin inside the Raspberry and share it only with the users that will use the application. In this way I could refuse the pairing from users that don't know the pin

Comment: Yea thats another option, and works great if its only for your raspberry pi. but its not really scalable if you ever wanted to ship this to other devices ect

Comment: Yes I know but  the scalability is not relevant in my project. However, do you have some ideas about the implementation of this solution? Thanks for the other options that you have suggested.

Comment: i would take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677164/ble-peripheral-pairing-pin-on-android