# Android BLE Peripheral (GATT Server) with PIN Authentication

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, peripherals, bluetooth-peripheral

I want to develop an Android BLE Peripheral (GATT Server) which works as a virtual Heart Rate Monitor. My major requirement is, Any Android/iOS Central application connecting with this Android BLE Peripheral, should perform secure PIN based bonding (Android Peripheral Application should generate a PIN & Android/iOS Central app must enter that PIN to connect). How do i implement this on Android Peripheral side?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653579/android-ble-peripheral-with-pin-pairing/42760006

Comment: @M.Kotzjan No, Question is similiar, but answer is not available

Comment: What exactly is your question then? As the other answer said you need to pair the devices which happens if your central tries to read a protected characteristic. You need to work with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer to create an android peripheral

Comment: Threre are multiple authentication stratergy like PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN = "The user will be prompted to enter a pin or an app will enter a pin for user", PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION = "The user will be prompted to confirm the passkey displayed on the screen or an app will confirm the passkey for the user", etc. But i want to enforce "PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN" from Peripheral side

Comment: I'll delete my answer since it is incorrect. You might get another answer that way